# TestNG Annotations order

Tags: java, testng

I have a question about the order of operations with TestNG annotations... I have the following code:

```
public class AnnotationsTest {

    @BeforeSuite(alwaysRun = true)
    public static void beforeSuite() {
        System.out.println("@BeforeSuite");
    }

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public static void beforeClass() {
        System.out.println("@BeforeClass");
    }

    @BeforeTest(alwaysRun = true)
    public static void beforeTest() {
        System.out.println("@BeforeTest");
    }

    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public static void beforeMethod() {
        System.out.println("@BeforeMethod");
    }

    @AfterSuite(alwaysRun = true)
    public static void afterSuite() {
        System.out.println("@AfterSuite");
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public static void afterClass() {
        System.out.println("@AfterClass");
    }

    @AfterTest(alwaysRun = true)
    public static void afterTest() {
        System.out.println("@AfterTest");
    }

    @AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public static void afterMethod() {
        System.out.println("@AfterMethod");
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        System.out.println("Test2");
    }
}
```

My output is the following:

[image]

My question is, why is @AfterTest method not run after each @Test annotation? Does TestNG treat the entire class as the 'Test'? It seems like this is the case because the @BeforeTest and @AfterTest are outside of the @BeforeClass and @AfterClass, but I wanted to be sure I understand. I assume I could use the @BeforeMethod and @AfterMethod in this case to execute before and after the test1 and test2 in this class. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is, why is @AfterTest method not run after each @Test
>   annotation?

As the [Documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html) says

> @AfterTest: The annotated method will be run after all the test
>   methods belonging to the classes inside the <**test**> tag have run.

and

> @BeforeTest: The annotated method will be run before any test method
>   belonging to the classes inside the <**test**> tag is run.

Comment: The documentation for 'BeforeTest' is incorrect then... as shown in my output, 'BeforeTest 'runs before THE FIRST test method, not any. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: `@BeforeTest` method runs only once , you can use `@BeforeMethod` if you want to run some method before each test case

Answer (score 0):

The main confusion here is with @Test annotation and  tag. Consider that you are executing above code from testng.xml file. And the way we write testng file tag sequence in that file is  methods . So it now each annotation will make sense. i.e. @Test is used for methods within that class. @BeforeMethod will get execute before each @Test annotation. And @BeforeTest annotation execute before classes mentioned in testng.xml file as you can see  tag encloses  tag. So short anwser for above question is @Test is used for menthod @BeforeMethod is executed before each @Test annoted method and @BeforeTest is executed before all methods and classes mentioned in  tag.

Answer (score 0):

`@AfterMethod` is the one that executes after `@Test` method. Similarly `@BeforeMethod` is the one that executes before each `@Test` method.

Your output shows the priority of methods running.